# Create a function and call it in one line of C# code

Tags: c#, delegates, c#-2.0

Can I dynamically create a function and invoke it (passing values into it) in one line of code?

Clarification:
I was looking for some way that could allow me to create an anonymous function and then calling it directly. Sort of:

```
delegate(string aa){ MessageBox.show(aa); }("Hello World!");
```

or something like that (I know the above code does not compile, but I wanted something close).

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this.

Comment: I do not want to clutter my class header by introducing another declaration.

Comment: Why not just use plain old inline code? Also I can't really see how a private method could be a big problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
new Action<int>(x => Console.WriteLine(x))(3);
```

it's not so readable but answering your question, you definitely can.

EDIT: just noticed you tagged it as c# 2.0, the answer above is for 3.5, for 2.0 it would be

```
new Action<int>(delegate(int x) { Console.WriteLine(x); })(3);
```

Comment: Thanks.. there seems to be a minor error though... Shouldn't it be new Action<string>(delegate(string x) { Console.WriteLine(x) }).Invoke("Hello World"); // I used delegate instead.

Comment: in 3.5 works (I checked it), in 2.0 you need to to write as you suggested

Answer (score 8):

The `.Invoke` is actually not needed; you can just write:

```
new Action<int>(x => Console.WriteLine(x))(3);
```

or for C# 2.0:

```
new Action<int>(delegate(int x) { Console.WriteLine(x); })(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To create an anonymous method use delegate:

```
delegate(...your arguments...) { ...your code... };
```

Edit: After the question was revised pablitos answer is more accurate.

Comment: To downvote an answer that is incorrect AFTER the question was revised/changed seems to me is not how voting should work.

Comment: @CKret: welcome to the internet, where people downvote you without a reason, all the time! ;) I've upvoted your answer though.

Comment: Nitpicking, actually the question did not change.. I goes back to clarify because I feel that I need to. But anyway, thanks.